# Table reversal required for multiple foreign keys rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, entity-relationship

I've been working through Hartl's book, and I don't know if this stems from my novice in Rails or Database principles, but I'm not fully understanding the purpose of reversing a table in order to designate a foreign key.

In the book, we reference a table like [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/images/figures/user_has_many_followed_users.png) . We determine we need the follower_id as a foreign key in the user model, so we specify it as such:

has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy

further down we determine we also need the followed_id as a foreign key, but rather than simply identifying the followed_id as an additional foreign key, we spoof a flipped table:

has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy

I'm having a hard time determining if this is a rails convention or required for db relationships.

Comment: You mean why we have used class_name to mention that its "Relationship"?

Comment: I guess my confusion is, why couldn't we just do something like:

has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy

rather than reversing the table? is that a rails violation or relationship violation, and why?